# Show that $\int_{0}^{\pi} xf(\sin(x))\text{d}x = \frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi}f(\sin(x))\text{d}x$

Tags: integration

Show that

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} xf(\sin(x))\text{d}x = \frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi}f(\sin(x))\text{d}x$$

this is so confusing. i have no idea how to even start. im thinking integration by parts but that doesnt seem right. 
hope you guys can help!!

Comment: You could start by clarifying your question. I have a hard time understanding what you are trying to do

Answer (score 3):

Use $\displaystyle\int_a^bf(x)\ dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)\ dx$

$$I=\int_0^\pi xf(\sin x)dx=\int_0^\pi(\pi+0-x)f\{\sin(\pi+0-x)\}dx$$

As $\sin(\pi-x)=\sin x,$

$$I=\int_0^\pi(\pi-x)f(\sin x)dx=?$$

Please let me know if this is not enough hint

Comment: sorry, what theorem is this. i don't follow.

Comment: @Danxe, Set $a+b-x=u$ in the left hand side

Comment: omg... i've never seen that b4. Sorry im just starting to learning integration in calculus 1. So im not sure what direction this is pointing me too.

Comment: @Danxe, Setting $a+b-x=u,-dx=du$  $$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_b^af(a+b-u)(-du)=-\int_a^bf(a+b-u)du$$  Now, $$\int_a^bf(a+b-u)du=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx$$  Finally, $$\int_c^df(x)dx=-\int_d^cf(x)dx$$

Comment: oh that's cool! i get it. but how does it get rid of the x in xf(sinx).

Comment: @Danxe, From my answer, $$I=\int_0^\pi(\pi-x)f(\sin x)dx=\pi\int_0^\pi f(\sin x)dx-\int_0^\pi xf(\sin x)dx$$  $$\implies I=\pi\int_0^\pi f(\sin x)dx-I$$

Comment: Omg... Now that's surprising... thanks so much... sorry it took so long. hard time dealing with integration. Thanks @lab bhattacharjee