# Integration with continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f$ be a continuous function in $[-1,1]$ with values in $\mathbb{R}$.

Please help me to prove that

$$\int_0^{\pi}x\,f(\sin(x))\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{\pi}\,f(\sin(x))\,dx$$

Thanks

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/971888/show-that-int-0-pi-xf-sinx-textdx-frac-pi2-int-0-pif-s

Answer (score 0):

Let $t=x- \frac{\pi}{2}$.

$$\int_0^{\pi}x\,f(\sin(x))\,dx-\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{\pi}\,f(\sin(x))\,dx$$

$$ = 
\int_0^{\pi}(x- \frac{\pi}{2})\,f(\sin x)\,dx  = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}t\,f(\cos t)\,dt=0$$

since $g(t)=tf(\cos t)$ is odd function.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
From the property of definite integral
$$\int_0^{2a} f(x) dx = \int_0^a f(x) dx + \int_0^a f(2a-x) dx $$
Where $2a = \pi$
So we can write the integral as
$$\int_0^{\pi} x f[\sin(x)] =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x f[\sin(x)] dx+ \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (\pi-x) f[\sin(\pi - x)] dx$$
That gives us
$$\int_0^{\pi} x f[\sin(x)] dx = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \pi f[\sin(x)] dx $$
As $ \sin (\pi-x) = \sin(x) $
So it gives
$$  \int_0^{\pi} x f[\sin(x)] dx = \pi[\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} f[\sin(x)] dx ] $$